# I need help to interpret a problem in measure theory.

Tags: measure-theory

I have the following problem.

For every natural number $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $\mathcal{A_n}$ be the sigma-algebra generated by $\{\{1\}, \dots, \{n\}\}$

- Show that $\mathcal{A_n}$ consists, besides $A = \emptyset$ and $A = \mathbb{N}$, of all subsets $A$ which satisfy $A \subset \{1, \dots , n\}$ or $m \in A$ for all $m \geq n+1$

I understand that I shall show that $\{1, \dots, n\} \in \mathcal{A_n}$ but I do not understand the "or $m \in A$ for all $m \geq n+1$" part

Comment: It means that the elements of $\mathcal A_n$ are the sets which either are subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ or contain some positive integers $\le n$ and all the integers strictly larger than $n$.

Comment: "... or the subsets..." is subsets in this part of your sentence, the subsets of $\mathbb{N}$? @G.Sassatelli

Comment: That sentence is no more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\forall m\geq n+1: m\in A$ means that $A\supseteq \Bbb N^+\setminus\{1,..,n\}$ , the relative complement of the set $\{1,..,n\}$

Basically, show that any $A$ in the sigma-algebra *may* contain some of the atoms of $\{1, .., n\}$, and must also contain either no natural number greater than $n$, or *all* natural numbers greater than $n$.

eg: $\sigma\big\{\{1\},\{2\}\big\} = \Big\{\underbrace{\varnothing, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1, 2\}}_{A\subseteq \{1,2\}}, \underbrace{\overbrace{\{3,\ldots\},}^{\{m~:~ m\geq 3\}} \{1,3,\ldots\},\{2,3,\ldots\},\{1,2,3,\ldots\}}_{A\supseteq\Bbb N^+\setminus\{1,2\}}\Big\} $

---

PS: The problem assumes that $0$ is not a natural number.

Comment: I just want to make sure that I understand 100 %, if you would change "...and must also contain..." to "...and $A$ must also contain..." would it still be same for you?

Comment: @Olba12 Yes.  Does the example make it clearer?

Comment: Yes! Now I understand the question, you did a great job!